# Build Google SDK example with Eclipse with release mode

Tags: android, google-drive-api, eclipse-adt

I try to build Google Drive SDK examples in Eclipse v22.01:
(The example website is as follows:) 
[https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924173/create-android-app-release-mode)

When I used debug build,it builded fine and executed fine on my table device.
However, when I tried to build it on release mode, I failed.

My process is as follows:
 1. Go to "File"->"Export"
 2. Create private keystore (This step succeeded.)
 3. Build apk

I've checked the post [Update your Proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924173/create-android-app-release-mode) and downloaded and replaced jars in Proguard
I also checked the post[Check the '"Android Private Libraries'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566367/proguard-problems-with-apk-creation) and checked items on "Order and Export" tab. But Still failed.

[Edit 1] I found the solution.

1. Just Uncheck the 'Drive API' (See the picture for reference)[image: Uncheck the item 'Drive API']
   (I am not sure if 'Android Dependencies' is needed or not. Maybe this could also be unchecked.)
2. I also add '-dontwarn com.google.**' to 'proguard-android.txt'
   And then it worked.

Here are the errors messages I got:

```
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Note: there were 1081 duplicate class definitions.
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.aa: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.aa: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$color
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.aa: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$drawable
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.aa: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.aa: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$color
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.aa: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$color
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.aa: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$drawable
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.aa: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$drawable
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.aa: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$drawable
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.aa: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$drawable
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.aa: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.aa: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$string
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$Cell: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$Cell: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$Cell: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$Cell: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager: can't find referenced class javax.inject.Inject
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager: can't find referenced class javax.inject.Singleton
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] Warning: there were 67 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity]          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity]          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity]          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:330)
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:212)
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:87)
[2013-07-24 12:03:43 - MainActivity]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, Please refer the "Edit 1" part.
Hope this would help anyone who got the same problem.

Comment: Please refer the "Edit 1" part. where i can refer?

Comment: On the problem description:

"[Edit 1] I found the solution.

Just Uncheck the 'Drive API' (See the picture for reference)"

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot (you have the google-play-services.jar), it looks like project isn't being built correct and this will only lead to more issues in the future.

Based on the link you provided, https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android that documentation Does tell you to just use the jar.

However, there are more complete instructions at https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Here it instructs to

1. use the **library project** at /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/
2. make proguard entries
3. modify your AndroidManifest.xml